# Restore transaction inapp purchase android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, restore

How to do restore transaction in in-app billing purchase android. So far I have searched in all links. I didn't find exact infromation. I have used `BillingHelper.restoreTransactionInformation(BillingSecurity.generateNonce())` but it returns nothing.
Can anyone help me to come out of this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the version 2 or the version 3 of the API?

Comment: Here i'm using version 3 of the API

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The V3 of the api does not require anymore to restore the purchases. Can directly query for purchased items.

Please read the section **Querying for Purchased Item** of:
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html
and the [getPurchases() method description](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getPurchases).

Comment: I'm having restore button for every product in my app.what method should be called for that restore on click listner. Can u pls share some source code for that.

Comment: Please post a new question on Stack Overflow and specify that you are using the V2. V2 and V3 and very different and it is messy to answer to both questions on the same Q&A. Please accept my answer if it was ok for your for the V3. Thank you.

Comment: In V2 I have sent restore transaction request.It is giving successful response.But it is not calling the method PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED.Can u pls guide me.

Comment: @poiuytrez i had made one product on consol now i am going to test it  but when i test from device it's display me sample title and price is 0.99$ can you tell me why this proble arise i had product with name pro version but it's display me sample title

Comment: @poiuytrez second thing if i upload two product on market and want to access in my app from two diffrent page then how can i distingute that which product i am going to purchase?

Comment: in my case Pruchase.getOrderId() returning empty string for already purchased app...any suggestion! Note: I did not upload it on play-store, using it from local system. Do i need to this mandatory?