# Google Play in-app billing v3 getSkuDetails() returns cached results even if IAP's prices were changed

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-games, android-billing

Google Play v3 API's IInAppBillingService.getSkuDetails() method returns cached results.

Let's look at this scenario:

1. I have an item called com.my.item in the Google Play Console with price $1
2. I run my game, invoked IInAppBillingService.getSkuDetails(), and indeed I get the $1 price.
3. Now I return to the Google Play Console and change the price to $2
4. I run my game again, invoke the method from (2) and still get $1.

Observations:

1. The Google Play purchase activity does show the correct price ($2)
2. Waiting for a while (2hours approx) doesn't help.
3. Clear Data on the Google Play app resolves the issue.
4. We tested on Galaxy Nexus (4.3), Samsung Galaxy S3 (4.1.2), with latest Google Play versions.

Anyone encountered this issue?

Thanks, Max.

Comment: I think you are using Restore transaction to store in app purchase data, am I? if yes then check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871115/restore-transaction-inapp-purchase-android and if you still go with it then "PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" may help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, it's not possible to programatically invalidate the cache, so you will get old results from getSkuDetails() until Google Play's cache refreshes, which should usually happen every 24 hours if there is good network connectivity.

You reported you waited for a few hours, so that's within expectations. Could you please try waiting ~24h and see if the cache gets updated? If it gets updated, then it's working as intended. If not, then there is something else that's wrong -- maybe Google Play is having trouble updating itself on that device.

Comment: i had made one product on consol now i am going to test it  but when i test from device it's display me sample title and price is 0.99$ can you tell me why this proble arise i had product with name pro version but it's display me sample title

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I will do just that and report my findings, could you please update your online dev-docs with this information, or did I miss it?

Comment: Verified, indeed after 24h the cache got invalidated and we saw the new price in the game. Thanks again Bruno

Comment: Hi Bruno! I just saw your Google I/O talk about In-App Billing v3. I think I found some severe problems with the docs and the API logic, but I can't get a hold of anyone at Google about this. Could I ask you to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921789/working-around-api-purchase-logic-flaws-for-consumables-in-google-plays-billing and forward it to the relevant people if you are no longer involved with this project? Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Its cached on the phone. Simply clear the google play cache (from the settings) of the phone

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. Pressed the "Clear cache" button on the "Google Play Store"(com.android.vending) under Settings>Apps.