# In app purchased mobile apps, how do I find out the user has paid for it when the app is reinstalled?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

I am using Ionic to develop an App, it will be ad-based, users can pay to remove ads.  So I figured I can use in-app purchase, so when user clicks remove ads button, allow the user to pay for it.  Now my question is, if the user uninstall the app, then re-install the app, how do I know he already paid for it?

I can think of two ways,

1. save the purchase information on phone.  The problem is if the user uninstalls the app, all data are removed, so this won't work.  (or maybe there is a way to save the data permanently, but what if he resets the phone?)
2. Is there a way for me to retrieve the purchase information from google and apple?

BTW, there is no backend server for my app.

[Edit] I looked at this plugin `https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase`

Is `store.refresh()` the correct API to call? Are non consumable products purchases/transactions tracked in ios and android billing system forever?

Thanks

Comment: I believe question is answered in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16933788/3376990

Comment: Play billing always return existing purchase if user already purchased a product,you can check the purchase even the user uninstall the app .

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  I think it is clear for android now.  Do you have any suggestions for Apple apps?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help.  It looks like the simplest way for me is to publish two versions, one paid version, and one free version.

Thanks